# How to pass Capcha security while calling web service?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Many of you fill like my question is stupid. But really I have face this issue.

When I call Web service to download audio file. It return me an html page content which ask me to pass Capcha security. check below screenshot.

[image]

I have used the below code to download File

```
NSString *strPathComponent = @"http://www.tipoff.tips/app/development/tipoffaudio/1472898051.caf";

NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirPath , [strPathComponent lastPathComponent]]
;
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:[strPathComponent
                                  stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];
__block BOOL isDownloaded = false;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession  sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"data of %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        NSLog(@"data of size %lu write at %@",[data length],filePath);
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:data attributes:nil]){
            NSLog(@"file write at %@",filePath);
        }
        else{

        }
    }
    isDownloaded = true;
}];
[task resume];
```

This was working earlier. but now it is not. I have also set all transport secutiry

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Normally it should return me content for CAF file but it return me HTML contact that look like the above screenshot.

Comment: the server you are accessing is using cloudflare to prevent automatic downloads of the file. See: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203366080-Why-do-I-see-a-captcha-or-challenge-page-Attention-Required-trying-to-visit-a-site-protected-by-CloudFlare-as-a-site-visitor-

Comment: Yes, You may be right. But How to check that my server configure with cloudflare.